# Formatting secondary HDD on Windows 8 with disabled Disk Management Snap-In

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive

After installing a new additional hdd on a Windows 8 machine (which was not configured by me but I have admin rights on) I want to format the drive in order to use it. Running `diskmgmt.msc` leads to an error saying the Disk Management snap-in was disabled. What is the best way to make my new hard drive usable?

In other words: how do I enable the snap-in or is there another tool I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, using the command line tool `diskpart`.

After opening it from the command line using `diskpart`, I was prompted to authenticate as an admin. Then the following commands accomplish what I was trying to do:

```
list disk
select disk 1
create partition primary
select partition 1
active
assign letter=E
format FS=NTFS
exit
```